# Spring Boot Security /login authentication with angularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So I have this project, which really all I want to do is be able to have a user log in and get access to a specific page:

**Security**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MainSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Resource
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/**", "/login/**", "/index.html", "/login.html", "/components/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/.sass-cache/**", "/services.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureForwardUrl("/login.html")
                .usernameParameter("user")
                .passwordParameter("password");



    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
```

When I sent the /login request from angularjs as a POST I was hitting the `UserDetailsServiceImpl` which is good, but the username was coming in empty.

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Resource
    private HttpSession httpSession;


    @Resource
    private UserDao userDao;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String user) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User userByEmail = userDao.findUserByEmail(user);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsImpl(userByEmail, httpSession.getId());

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

So I did some googling and it said that the /login request has to be `GET`, which in itself confused me, should we really be plonking the username and password into the url? Or am I thinking about this wrong. Anyway, here's the angularJS code:

```
$scope.loginUser = function () {
    $scope.user.user = $scope.email;
    $scope.user.password = $scope.password;
    $http.get("/login", { params: {username: $scope.user.user, password: $scope.user.password}});
```

I no longer hit the breakpoints now within `UserDetailsServiceImpl` and rather I am getting a 404.

**UPDATE**

After updating the processing url, I now post it but the username that get's passed server-side is empty

```
$scope.loginUser = function () {
    $scope.user.username = $scope.email;
    $scope.user.password = $scope.password;
    $http.post("/api/authentication", $scope.user);
```

Everything up to here is fine, it's just when java handles it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my AngularJS `$http.post` request, I solved it by adding headers for 'application/x-www-form-urlendcoded' as it is not the default header:

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/authentication',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: 'username=' + $scope.email + '&password=' + $scope.password
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular you have not a `loginPage` because you are writing a SPA and page navigation is managed by Angular itself.

You should use `loginProcessingUrl` that defines only the login submission url

```
    .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
```

To submit you login you need to do a `POST` not a `GET`. Probably links mean url to access a login page not to submit.

In the example above you have to do a `POST` using url `/api/authentication` with a body containing `username` and `password`

Also if i've seen you already found the solution, i've published a project based on Spring Boot 2.0 and angular 6 (angularjs is quite outdated) with spring security and a stateful authentication (the same you were searching for)

https://github.com/ValerioMC/vforge-stateful-auth

It's just a starting point.

Comment: Get the same issue as before with the username be sent is empty

Comment: edited answer. try to follow tutorial in the link. it's a complete example, and should help you. You will find also GitHub source code

Comment: I've already been through that exact article, they do a seperate authentication getting the user, they never actually post the details. Once authenticated they just redirect to "/login"

Comment: add related code link on GitHub. Once the user has been authenticated it's up to you to manage redirect

Comment: This is incorrect, formlogin() by default will use spring generated login page at /login if not specified differently.